# PHP Pagination for 1,2,3... vs 1,2,3,4,5,etc

Tags: php, sql, pagination

I am having an issue where I am doing a query and it is coming back with about 100 pages, I was hoping to have it come back with 1,2,3...30,31...99,100 instead of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,etc. please see below for working code that returns back results as unwanted format, I am new here so if this question is written wrong please let me know and I will make necessary changes , thanks in advance:

```
function getPage($stmt, $pageNum, $rowsPerPage)
{
$offset = ($pageNum - 1) * $rowsPerPage;
$rows = array();
$i = 0;
while(($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC, 
 SQLSRV_SCROLL_ABSOLUTE,         $offset + $i)) && $i < $rowsPerPage)
{
array_push($rows, $row);
$i++;
}
return $rows;
}

// Set the number of rows to be returned on a page.
$rowsPerPage = 30;

// Connect to the server.
$serverName = 'test';
$connOptions = array("Database"=>"test");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connOptions);
if (!$conn)
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

//  Define and execute the query.  
// Note that the query is executed with a "scrollable" cursor.
$sql = "select * from info";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'static' ));
if ( !$stmt )
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

// Display the selected page of data.
echo "<table border='1px' align='center'>";
$pageNum = isset($_GET['pageNum']) ? $_GET['pageNum'] : 1;
$page = getPage($stmt, $pageNum, $rowsPerPage);

foreach($page as $row)
echo "<tr><td>$row[0]</td><td>$row[1]</td><td>$row[2]</td><td>$row[3]</td></tr>";

echo "</table>";
?>
<table align='center'>
<?php
// Get the total number of rows returned by the query.
// Display links to "pages" of rows.
$rowsReturned = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);
if($rowsReturned === false)
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
elseif($rowsReturned == 0)
{
echo "No rows returned.";
exit();
}
else
{     
// Display page links.
$numOfPages = ceil($rowsReturned/$rowsPerPage);
for($i = 1; $i<=$numOfPages; $i++)
{
 $pageLink = "?pageNum=$i";
 print("<a href=$pageLink>$i</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;");
}
echo "<br/><br/>";
}   



 sqlsrv_close( $conn );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just mean the links at the bottom of your page? If so you have this code:

```
// Display page links.
$numOfPages = ceil($rowsReturned/$rowsPerPage);
for($i = 1; $i<=$numOfPages; $i++)
{
    $pageLink = "?pageNum=$i";
    print("<a href=$pageLink>$i</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;");
}
```

Modify this to render just  the first three links, then your ellipses (...) separator and then the final page number.

**EDIT to add pseudo code**
This is messy but hopefully gives you the idea, create your function, make it work and then post a new question asking how to make it prettier (for example tidy up the ifs, add logic to only render a single set of ellipses, don't repeat any rendering code).

```
$numOfPages = ceil($rowsReturned/$rowsPerPage);
$renderedEllipses = false;
for($i = 1; $i<=$numOfPages; $i++)
{
    //If you always want to render pages 1 - 3
    if($i < 4) {
        //render link
    }

    //If you always want to render current page number
    else if($i == $pageNum) {
        //render link
        //reset ellipses
        $renderedEllipses = false;
    }

    //if you always want the last page number
    else if ($i == $numOfPages - 1) {
        //render link
    }

    //make sure you only do this once per ellipses group
    else {
      if (!$renderedEllipses){
          print("...");
          $renderedEllipses = true;
      }
    }
}
```

**EDIT added ellipses test**
The `$renderedEllipses` flag will stop hundreds of ellipses being rendered.

Comment: Hi JohnMark12, I appreciate your help with this unfortunately I am stuck on how to do the ellipses as if user goes to page 8 it will need to change to 1,2,3...8,9...99,100 and if user goes to page 30 then 1,2,3..30,31...,99,100 if that makes sense, any help would be highly appreciated. @JohnMark13

Comment: John Awesome , this is very close to what I need however I need to render pages inbetween current page and last page, any idea how to achieve this bud, you are a big help! - @JohnMark13

Comment: I am going to mark your answer as correct as it helped me to achieve my end goal, Thanks for your help bud!

Comment: Hi. Consider the $i == $pageNum condition which renders a link  to the current page. Then consider something like `if(abs($i - $pageNum) == 1)` which will return true for numbers one either side of the current page. Onwards!

Comment: 1 last question my ellipses is producing alot of dots so for some reason it is got a string like this : 1,2,3...................................65,.................................129,130 any ideas how to achieve this I am satisfied otherwise :)! - @JohnMark13

Comment: This question should really be on StackOverflow, but seeing as I've started. I put a comment in the original code (make sure you only do this once...). One way of tracking it would be to have a flag say $renderedElipses set it to false before the loop. In the loop set it to false whenever you render a link, but when you render the ellipses, set it to true. How does that help? Before rendering the ellipses check the state of your flag, don't render ellipses again if it is true.

Comment: I,ve actually asked this question on StackOverflow as well (dont worry I will copy and paste your answer and give you credit once done unless you would like to) anyway do you mean  to put define('$renderedElipss', FALSE); at the beginning and between the else if statements? @JohnMark13

Comment: also as a sidenote Ive only done the end else statement once for the whole code block. @JohnMark13

Comment: See edit which shows how ellipses could be handled.

Comment: Perfect, I cant ask for more, your answer is marked correct will copy over to StackOverflow also, thanks again bud. @JohnMark13